# Issue converting epoch time to standard convention in Perl

Tags: perl, time, epoch

In Perl I am trying to convert a variable containing millisecond epoch time variable `$adjSendTime` to standard convention using the following code:

```
$timeLabel = sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", (($adjSendTime/3600000) % 24), (($adjSendTime/60000) % 60), $currentSecond);
```

The issue is that whenever it has reach the 59th second the minute portion of the time will be on minute higher than it should be.  The output looks something like

```
11:58:57
11:58:58
11:59:59
11:59:00
11:59:01
```

The calculation for `$adjSendTime` is as follows:

```
# Determine number of hours between local time and UTC.
# This code is needed to compare timestamps in local time with those in epoch time.
# This code only works in time zones with current time less than UTC time.
@timeArray = gmtime();
$utcHour = $timeArray[2];
@timeArray = localtime();
$localHour = $timeArray[2];
# calculate number of milliseconds between current time and UTC time
$utcShift = ($utcHour - $localHour + 24) % 24;
$utcShift = $utcShift*60*60*1000;

...

if ($field[$i] =~ /^\[29997]=/) {
  $sendTimestamp = $field[$i];
  $sendTimestamp =~ s/.*=(\d*).*/$1/;
  # convert send time to local time.
  $adjSendTime = $sendTimestamp - $utcShift;
}
```

The calculation for `$currentSecond` is in two different parts of the code.  The first piece occurs the first time through the loop when `$FIRST = 1;`. `$FIRST` is never reset to 1 again after this if statement is executed.

```
$second = ($adjSendTime/1000) % 60;
if ($FIRST) {
  $currentSecond = $second;
  $prevSeqId = $seqId;
  $FIRST = 0;
}
```

and in the subroutine `resetCounters` where every value that is calculated in the script is reinitialize to 0.  This subroutine is called is called at the start of every new second in the input log file.

```
sub resetCounters
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# resets all metrics counters
# -----------------------------------------------------------
{
  $tps = 0;
  $mps = 0;
  $batch = 0;
  $maxBatch = 0;
  $avgBatch = 0;
  $latency = 0;
  $latencySum = 0;
  $maxLatency = 0;
  $avgLatency = 0;
  $overThreshold = 0;
  $percentOver = 0;
  $zeroLatencyCount = 0;
  $currentSecond = $second;
  @latencies = ();
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why Perl would be doing this because when I find the remainder via long hand division I do not have this issue?  I realize that I could use datetime to possibly find the hour and minute for this calculation, but I would still be interested in determining what is wrong with my calculation so that I can hopefully avoid issues like this in the future when using `%` in Perl.

Comment: Where are you getting `$currentSecond` from? It would appear you're incrementing that somehow while not changing `$adjSendTime`

Comment: Please show your code for the complete loop. It looks like the error is in a statement preceding the one you have shown.

Comment: I must apologize for my lack of Perl experience to all and the fact that I cannot put all my code for you to look at.  Company policy says I can only post required portions of code online to solve issue and the less the better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple version which uses two built-in perl functions:

```
my $timeLabel = sprintf "%02d:%02d:%02d", (localtime($adjSendTime/1000))[2,1,0];
```

For anything much more complicated than this, I would likely use an external module, but I just don't see much point in doing so for this particular need.

Comment: This was the best answer because everyone always makes the assumption that you are able to use external modules like DateTime.  Unfortunately, my company is very restrictive on what external API's and code they will allow in certain environments.  In the environment I was working in I could only use Perl built in modules like localtime.

Answer (score 11):

Why reinvent the wheel when you can use [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.72/lib/DateTime.pm)?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $epoch=1254121251.352329;

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch=>$epoch,time_zone => "America/Chicago");

print $dt->ymd . " " . $dt->hms . "\n";
```

The output is:

```
2009-09-28 02:00:51
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on.  Always use existing, tested library routines, most especially for date/time coding.

Comment: `time_zone => 'local'` for local time.

Comment: His existing code implies he hash `$epoch=12541212513523;` instead of `$epoch=1254121251.3523;`

Comment: @ikegami: `my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch=>($epoch/1000),time_zone => "America/Chicago");`

Comment: @CanSpice, That's a step backwards from the `DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch1000/1000, time_zone => 'local')` I already mentioned.

Comment: DateTime is not allowed in the environment I am running this script because my company only allows builtin Perl modules in the environment I am using this script.  It is a good solution for most cases except in companies like mine where external APIs are rarely trusted and they prefer in-house solutions.

Comment: [Non](http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/local-lib-1.008004/lib/local/lib.pm)[sense!](http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.39/lib/App/perlbrew.pm)

Comment: @Matt Pascoe, Accepting code Stackoverflow while refusing code from CPAN is nonsense.

Answer (score 7):

This can be achived simply using core tools: [POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX)'s `strftime` in combination with [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html).

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
say strftime('%H:%M:%S', localtime( $mstime/1000 ));
```

[DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) is a great module, but it's needlessly slow for this job. And much wordier.

```
use DateTime qw( );
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $mstime/1000, time_zone => 'local');
say $dt->strftime('%H:%M:%S');
```