# Perl: How to convert milliseconds to timestamp or date

Tags: perl, date

I need to convert time in milliseconds to date of format: YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
Please help

Comment: Milliseconds since when?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764670/issue-converting-epoch-time-to-standard-convention-in-perl

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Milliseconds" don't denote time, they denote duration. Sounds like you have a unix epoch time stamp multiplied by 1000 with milliseconds added.

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
my $formatted = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($ts/1000));
```

Or `gmtime`